# Node Js Is Not Reading React JS Post Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

My project consists of React Js on the frontend, Node Js on the backend, and MySQL as the DB.

I am attempting to push data from the frontend to the backend, and the backend is not reading any of the formdata values, nor is it receiving the file. Below is my code for the frontend and backend. I do not see any incorrect configurations. However, I could be overlooking something. Any advice is appreciated.

React Js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './NewsAndFlyerUploadFlyers.css';
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';
//Repositories
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const NewsAndFlyerUploadFlyers = () => {
    const [flyerName, setFullName] = useState(null);
    const [flyerEventDate, setFlyerEventDate] = useState(null);
    const [flyerDescription, setFlyerDescription] = useState(null);
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
    const [statusMessage, setStatusMessage] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const Navigate = useNavigate();

    const submitForm = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/Flyer/Flyer_Upload';
        
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('flyerName', flyerName);
        data.append('flyerEventDate', flyerEventDate);
        data.append('flyerDescription', flyerDescription);
        for (var x = 0; x < selectedFile.length; x++){
            data.append('files', selectedFile[x]);
        }
        
        Axios.post(url, data)
        .then((response) => { 
            if (response.data.status == 500){
                setStatusMessage(response.data.message);
            }
            else if (response.data.message == 'All fields must be filled out...'){
                setStatusMessage(response.data.message);
            }
            else {
                Navigate('/NewsAndFlyers');
            }
        });
        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <div className='newsAndFlyersUploadFlyersBody'>
                <h1>Upload A Flyers</h1>
                <div className='flyerInfoFormBody'>
                <p className='flyerName'>*Event Name: <input name='flyerName' placeholder='Event Name' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)} /></p>
                <p className='flyerEventDate'>*Event Date: <input name='flyerEventDate' placeholder='Event Date' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setFlyerEventDate(e.target.value)} /></p>
                <p className='flyerDescription'>*Flyer Description: <textarea name='flyerDescription' placeholder='Flyer Description' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setFlyerDescription(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                <p>*Upload the flyer.</p>
                <input className='uploadFiles' type='file' name='file' required onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files)} /></div>
                <button className='uploadButton' onClick={submitForm}>Upload Flyer</button>
                <h2>{statusMessage}</h2>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </>
    );
}

export default NewsAndFlyerUploadFlyers;
```

Node Js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/db');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const SqlDbStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
//----------------------------------------- BEGINNING OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    store: new SqlDbStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxxx',
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:{
        maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
        secure: false
    }
}));
const multerFlyerDestination = './routes/Flyers';
const flyerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, files, cb){ 
    return cb(null, multerFlyerDestination)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb){
    return cb(null, file.fieldname);
  } 
});
const uploadFlyer = multer({ storage: flyerStorage }).single('file');
//----------------------------------------- END OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
router.post('/Flyer_Upload', (req, res) => {
  const flyerName = req.body.flyerName;
  const flyerEventDate = req.body.flyerEventDate;
  const flyerDescription = req.body.flyerDescription;
  const flyerID = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;

  console.log('\nflyerName: ' + flyerName);
  console.log('\nflyerEventDate: ' + flyerEventDate);
  console.log('\nflyerDescription: ' + flyerDescription);
  console.log('\nflyerID: ' + flyerID);

  uploadFlyer(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return res.status(500).json(err)
    } else if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err)
    }

    const directory = path.dirname(req.path);
    console.log('File path: ' + directory);
    return res.status(200).send(req.files);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made middleware for multer but did not call the middleware
and you will get your files inside `req.body`

```
router.post('/Flyer_Upload', uploadFlyer.array('files'), (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body)
.
.
}
```

Comment: But I call uploadFlyer inside router.post which calls multer… isn’t that still the right thing? I also got an error when I tried this before posting.

Comment: formdata will not be available in ```req.body```

Comment: I will try this again now and let you know.

Comment: That uploaded everything, but now I get “the file is not displayed in the text editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text endcoding” when I click on the file. It is also missing the file extension on the side. The function doesn’t return successful to the frontend so I’m not redirected. I should also mention that it is only one file that I am uploading so should it be uploadFlyer.single(‘file’)?

Comment: The file is also not being renamed the filename

Comment: I fixed it. I had to use file.originalname. I appreciate your help!